# Umbraco Razor get children of a child

Tags: razor, umbraco7

I'm trying to build a menu with submenus using razor, which I'm not familiar with, and so far I can get the elements of the top level with:

```
@{ var selection = CurrentPage.Site().Children.Where("Visible"); }
```

and then:

```
@foreach (var item in selection)
{
    <li class="@(item.IsAncestorOrSelf(CurrentPage) ? "current" : null)">
        <a href="@item.Url">@item.Name</a>
    </li>
 }
```

However, if I try to test if the next level exists with:

```
@foreach (var item in selection)
{
    <li class="@(item.IsAncestorOrSelf(CurrentPage) ? "current" : null)">
        <a href="@item.Url">@item.Name</a>
    </li>

    @if (item.Children.Where("Visible").Any()) { <li><p>has children</p></li> } 

}
```

I get an error.

```
@if (item.Descendants().Where("Visible").Any()) { <li><p>has children</p></li> }
```

This doesn't work either.

Can anyone enlighten me as to what I'm doing wrong? I assume it is possible somehow but googling the problem hasn't thrown anything up yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This must be a Parser Error. You've already declared "@" at the beginning of your foreach loop, therefore you don't need it before your "if" statement.

Change this:

```
@if (item.Children.Where("Visible").Any()) { <li><p>has children</p></li> }
```

to this:

```
if (item.Children.Where("Visible").Any()) { <li><p>has children</p></li> }
```